# post file using ruby curl easy.http_put (data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl, put

I have a task to send a file using HTTP PUT in ruby.

In Command prompt i am able to get success response using the following command.

```
curl -X PUT -vN https://myexample.com/blah/myaccount --insecure -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" -H "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" -d @/myfile.wav
```

While trying to send the request using Curl::Easy in ruby. I get a error response code stating something wrong with audio.

```
c = Curl::Easy.new("https://myexample.com/blah/myaccount")
c.timeout = 30
c.ssl_verify_host = false
c.http_put ( "Content-Transfer-Encoding=base64;Connection=keep-alive;Content-Type=audio%2fwav;#{File.read(/myfile.wav)}")
```